# Node.js - Socket.io - Associate request with response

Tags: node.js, tcp, socket.io

I'm trying to communicate with my a source measuring unit by TCP/IP using the net package in Node.js. No problem to connect to the instrument and run queries.

However I'm trying to get some association between a request and its response. For example, let's say I want to measure and extract some current out of the instrument. I would do like

```
socket.on('data', function( data ) {
    console.log( data.toString( 'utf8' ) );
});

socket.write("print( smua.measure.i() );\r\n", 'utf8'); // This will directly print the response into the socket
```

Which works fine.

However, there's no way of knowing that the output comes from that particular query since it's all asynchronous. Any leads on the solution I could adopt ?

In the GPIB protocol (If I got it correctly) I query the instrument (or the socket...) for the response, which makes things easier since it's all sequential. But how can I do this in TCP ?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Since you control the request and the response, you can put a request ID in each request/response.  Just use a monotomically increasing counter as your request id and in each response, just send back the request id that came in with the request.  Then you know the request and response with the same id are the ones that are associated.